# What is the difference between getByText and screen.getByText in RTL

Tags: react-testing-library

I'm new to [React-Testing-Library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) and found a couple of examples on the web of people using `view.getByText('Greeting')` and `screen.getByText('Greeting')`, like in the following code.

Is there any difference between them?

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
    import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
    import { App } from "./App";
    
    test("render the correct context", ()=>{
      const view = render(<App />);
      view.getByText("Greeting");
      screen.getByText("Greeting");
    });
```

Can anyone please tell me in detail?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

TLDR; They are **very often** the same thing.

#### The difference

`getByText` will query inside [baseElement](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#baseelement)

`screen.getByText` will query inside `document.body`

We usually don't specify a custom `container` or `baseElement` inside the `render` function, this causes it to default to `document.body`.

Therefore `getByText` and `screen.getByText`--or any of the other queries--are usually interchangeable.

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'

test("render the correct context", ()=>{
  const { getByText } = render(<App />, { baseElement });
  getByText("Greeting"); // queries inside baseElement (which usually means document.body)
  screen.getByText("Greeting"); // queries inside document.body
});
```

---

#### Which one should you use

I don't think this matters much and you should be fine either way. That said, the creator of the library [advocates for screen](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#not-using-screen) and also mentions you should avoid using the `container` or `baseElement` render options.

---

#### Useful links

- [why you should use screen](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#not-using-screen)
- [screen docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#screen)
- [render options](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#render-options)

Comment: Hey Doug, Thanks for answer,
Recently, I found out we can import getByText directly from '@testing-library/react',
Does it make any difference compare to the getByText  from render ?

Answer (score 1):

The `view` is just the result of `render`, so in the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/marko-testing-library/api#render-result) we see:

> The render method returns a promise which resolves with an object that
> has a few properties:
>
> ...queries#
>
> The most important feature of render is that the queries from DOM
> Testing Library are automatically returned with their first argument
> bound to the results of rendering your component.

So you have your objected generated by your `App`, that you can query. [`screen`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#screen) is

> screen#
>
> All of the queries exported by DOM Testing Library accept a container
> as the first argument. Because querying the entire document.body is
> very common, DOM Testing Library also exports a screen object which
> has every query that is pre-bound to document.body (using the within
> functionality).

So querying here queries the entire body always.

Comment: The docs link you've provided is incorrect possibly I need help for React Testing Library here is the link https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library

Comment: @BabluAhmed Scroll down and click "docs" on that link - https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library#docs. You'll see it's the same site. `rtl` build on top of the more general library.

Comment: I can't believe they made an object called 'screen'.  The window already has one:
> screen
< Screen {availWidth: 1920, availHeight: 1200, width: 1920, height: 1200, colorDepth: 30, …}